# How can i use global slash command in discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've created a simple slash command. It works on the only guild. before that, I was using v12. Now I wanna switch to v13.
Now how can I make these global slash commands?

Code

````js
client.on ("ready", () => {
 
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} Has logged in`)
  client.user.setActivity(`/help | ${client.user.username}`, { type: "PLAYING" })

    const guildId = "914573324485541928"
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
    let commands

    if (guild) {
      commands = guild.commands
    } else {
      commands = client.application.commands
    }

    commands.create({
      name: 'ping',
      description: 'Replies with pong'
    })
    commands.create({
      name: 'truth',
      description: 'Replies with truth'
    })

  }); 
  client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()){
      return
    }

    const { commandName, options } = interaction 

    if (commandName === 'ping'){
      interaction.reply({
        content: 'pong'
      })
    }
    ```

I'm new in v13 so please explain it simply :|
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the `guild` declaration. Your code checks if `guild` is truthy, and uses the guild if it is. Otherwise, it will use global commands

```js
const guild = null 
// any falsy value is fine (undefined, false, 0, '', etc.)
```

Comment: but its not showing in other server

Comment: When you invite the bot to the server, make sure it has `application.commands` scope. It's not enough to have it in the server while inviting to a different server with the scope

Comment: Also keep in mind that global commands can take up to 1 hour to refresh/update

Comment: @MrMythical Working Now 

Comment: @MrMythical It's been 8 hours but still no error in the console but when I use it its something like this  https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/741358747665956956/915096121293033502/unknown.png

Comment: Hmm... whenever that happened to me, I just used a different command and they all worked perfectly. I suggest using `REST` though since it instantly puts the commands