# I'm in need of help registering for all guilds globally, can someone assist me?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm looking to register for all guilds globally instead of registering for just my guild ID, just so I can use slash commands in my friend's server (plus any other server it's in), yet I don't know how. I'm a bit new to discord.js.

I was wondering if someone could help me register for all guilds globally...

Extra information - I'm following reconlx's Discord.js v13 tutorials.

This is the part of my code which I need help looking at and modifying. There's a line in his command handler talking about registering for all guilds at `await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);`, yet I'm not sure what it means...

```
client.on("ready", async () => {
        // Register for a single guild
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("938823675535319050")
        await guild.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands).then((cmd) => {
            const getRoles = (commandName) => {
                const permissions = arrayOfSlashCommands.find(
                    (x) => x.name === commandName
                ).userPermissions;

                if(!permissions) return null;
                return guild.roles.cache.filter(
                    (x) => x.permissions.has(permissions) && !x.managed
                );
            };

            const fullPermissions = cmd.reduce((accumulator, x) => {
                const roles = getRoles(x.name);
                if(!roles) return accumulator;

                const permissions = roles.reduce((a, v) => {
                    return [
                        ...a,
                        {
                            id: v.id,
                            type: 'ROLE',
                            permission: true,
                        },
                    ];
                }, []);

                return [
                    ...accumulator,
                    {
                        id: x.id,
                        permissions,
                    },
                ];
            }, []);

            guild.commands.permissions.set({ fullPermissions });
        });

        // Register for all the guilds the bot is in
        // await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
    });
```

Looking forward to some solutions, if you could assist, it would help a lot.

Comment: Any clues here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149557/how-can-i-use-global-slash-command-in-discord-js-v13

Answer (score 0):

You can register global commands using the `Client.application.commands.set()` method, passing in an Array of `ApplicationCommandDataResolvables` into the method. However, please be aware a caveat of global commands is that they take up to an hour for changes to reflect across Discord.

See this:

```
client.application.commands.set(commands)
// ^^^                          ^^^^^^^^
// Client is your Discord.Client  Commands is the list of commands
```